# В чем разница в Java между class и public class?

Tags: java, ооп

Дело в том, что в материале который я изучаю, когда дошло до модификаторов доступа, то описание коснулось только модификаторов доступа членов класса(переменных и методов). Но я часто вижу конструкции где возле имени класса стоит модификатор доступа `public`вот например `public class Foo { }`. Еще я иногда вижу когда создается класс без модификатора `public` но в конструкторе он присутствует:

```
class Foo {
  public Foo () {}
}
```

В чем разница между `public class` и `class` по умолчанию?

Comment: по умолчанию `package-private` для класса

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641876/java-the-difference-between-class-classname-and-public-class-classname

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Класс без модификатора доступа по-умолчанию является `package-private` (доступные только внутри пакета, в котором объявлены).

`public` делает класс доступным откуда угодно.

Почитайте тут: [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Comment: Тоесть если я создам папку с пакетом А модификатором доступа `public` то из папки с пакетом B я смогу вызвать этот класс без какого либо импорта?

Comment: @PIXELWORLD нет. Но приватный даже с импортом не вызовешь.

Answer (score 1):

Если кратко, то `Public` делает твой `class` доступным из любого пакета.

Comment: А зачем тогда конструкторам класса ставят иногда модификатор `public`?